# Add tab bar controller in existing navigation controller and pass existing running object thought out screens

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, segue

[image]I have searched many forums but didn't find any appropriate solution. 
I have a working project with is build with `UINavigationController`. Now I want to break some part of it with `UITabBarController`.The problem is I had an active object which is passed throughout the screens with the help of `prepareForSegue` method.
How can I integrate new `UITabBar` and also pass this active object in any screen?

If you see the image, the red color section was working fine for me. I had list of objects in the table view controller and when I select any one I sued to show the details related to it in another screen.Green area is tab bar which I embeded on navigation controller and I want to send selected object from add player list to second tab bar Guesture screen.

Comment: basically , you want to pass data from add player list to Guesture screen???

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't understand your question. So, i am only explaining how can we add
>   UITabBarController on NavigationController. Please Update Question !!

Import `MyTabBarController.h` (Your tab bar controller file name) in `AppDelegate.h`

```
#import "MyTabBarController.h"
```

Now, update `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method using following code in `AppDelegate.m`

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
//Use your tab bar controller name instead of MyTabBarController
        UITabBarController *tabController = [[MyTabBarController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabController];
        self.window.rootViewController = nav;
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; // choose color
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;

}
```

Comment: I need the steps to follow.I tried this way I am able to get the table view controls but I am not very familiar with the process how it works.And also I have added tab bar by embeding navigation controll.

Comment: can you add some screenshots/code so i can understand your problem?

Comment: I have updated the question.Please let me know if its not clear

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference to your activeObject in your AppDelegate.  Then have each view controller reference this activeObject.

In AppDelegate.swift

```
let activeObject = ActiveObject() //Note : Assuming you set up a class for your object
```

Then, you need to send this object to your view controllers down the stack.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
     let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController    //Find the tab bar controller
                        if let tabBarViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers {
                            let navigationController = tabBarViewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController //Access the navigation controller of the first view controller
                            let myViewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! MyViewController
                            MyViewController.activeObject = activeObject
                        }
```

Do this for all of the tabs that need a reference to your object.
Remember to give your Tab View Controllers (called MyViewController in my example code) a reference to activeObject after the class declaration

```
var activeObject:ActiveObject!
```